# Fan flow direction

Tags: cooling, fan

can someone tell me how can I place my fans for optimal cooling.

My main problem is in fan #1 and #3...

I don't know what is better:

1. change flow direction of fan #1 or
2. change flow direction of fan #3

My current situation:

[image: my fans flow direction]

Comment: I guess if you convert CPU (#3) fan flow to #1 direction it will be better.

All fan directions point to out but #3 flows to inside. Thats the point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cold(er) air should **enter the front** and warm air should **exit the back** of the PC. This is to ensure that maximum heat is taken up by the air as it travels through the box and that the air keeps moving and doesn't become stuck swirling inside the box.

[image]

Comment: In my case the fan is on the other side... is still OK to just turn the flow direction?

Comment: @Wolfy, yes, sure it's OK. In this picture the fan is on the other side of the heatsink tower just to suck in the hot air from RAM.

Comment: Unless the heatsink is shaped that should be okay. Some are designed to minimise the dead zone behind the fan hub and need to be mounted in a particular configuration.